# Filling a new vector by sampling without replacement from an old one

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shuffle

Is there a good and efficient algorithm in C++ for sampling without replacement that could easily be applied to the following function?

It takes two vectors, `new` and `old`, and fills the latter in a loop by repeatedly sampling from the former (`rng.i0` is a random number generator function that I use to return a random integer between 0 and given value).

```
void diluationexpansionstep(std::vector<long> &oldpopulation,
                            std::vector<long> &newpopulation,
                            long newpopsize)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= newpopsize;i++) {
        int index_a = rng.i0(oldpopulation.size());
        newpopulation.push_back(oldpopulation[index_a]);
    }
}
```

**Update::**

Thank you for helpful responses. Because i want to use my own RNG rather than the inbuilt one in C++ i ended constructing the following Fisher Yates based function where rng.i0 is a function that returns a random intiger between 0 and integer parameter.

```
void FisherYatesShuffle(vector<long> &indices){
    for (int k = 0; k < indices.size(); k++) {
        int r = k + rng.i0(indices.size()-k);
        swap(indices[k], indices[r]);
        }
    }

void diluationexpansionstep(std::vector<long> &oldpopulation,
                            std::vector<long> &newpopulation,
                            long newpopsize){
    vector<long> indices(oldpopulation.size());
    std::iota(std::begin(indices),std::end(indices),0);
    FisherYatesShuffle(indices);
    for (int i = 0; i <= newpopsize-1;i++){
        newpopulation.push_back(oldpopulation[indices[i]]);
        }
    }
```

As far as i can tell this work accurately and reasonably quickly.

Comment: Look at [Fisher-Yates_shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Isn't your example sampling _with_ replacement since you're not removing anything from `oldpopulation` and you're not ensuring that the indexes you're selecting with aren't dups (unless that's what `rng.i0` is doing, which I don't recognize)?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to ask here. Can you clarify "without replacement" and could you provide *rng.i0(...)* because you are asking for "could easily be applied to the following function". What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Elyasin - I assume "without replacement" means pick a random element from the source, then pick a subsequent element from the diminished source (with the first element removed), etc.  In other words, the standard definition of selection "without replacement" vs. selection "with replacement".

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurately described as 'without repetition'?

Comment: @Elyasin - perhaps, but the statisticians decided on [without replacement](http://stattrek.com/statistics/dictionary.aspx?definition=Sampling_without_replacement) quite awhile ago.

Comment: C++17 [`std::sample`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample). A sample implementation is in the [`sample` proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3925.pdf). (The tag dispatch in there is wrong, but you can use either version of `__sample` directly (after renaming) for your purposes.)

Comment: My example is currently sampling with replacement. Was looking for adaptation that allow it to sample without replacement (i.e having picked random element from source, would then pick a subsequent element from source with element removed.

Answer (score 0):

A "good and efficient" algorithm for minimizing developer time and maximizing correctness, using `std::random_shuffle` from `<algorithm>`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<long> random_sample_without_replacement(const vector<long>& source, int newpopsize)
{
    assert(newpopsize >= 0 && newpopsize <= source.size());
    auto result { source };
    std::random_shuffle(result.begin(), result.end());
    result.resize(newpopsize);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    vector<long> test { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    auto result { random_sample_without_replacement(test, 5) };
    for (auto& e : result) cout << e << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Working example here.](http://ideone.com/TIZDWm)

Comment: I am not sure if that is an answer to the question.

Comment: @T.C. what part of "good and efficient" measured by "minimizing developer time and maximizing correctness" is not met here?

Comment: Start from "using a deprecated function that has been removed in C++17".

Comment: @T.C. Well gosh, I guess I didn't know that. But since the tag on this question is C++11 I don't know that it matters.  I guess when this matters this code sample can be changed to `std::shuffle`.  Will it then be "good and efficient" or not?

Comment: you've introduced two constraints the original didn't have - you can't have a newpopsize of 0 and you can't have a newpopsize larger than the source.

Comment: @kfsone You cannot sample w/o replacement if newpopsize is larger than the source size.  I will make the other correction.  (This is a lot of effort for a question whose OP will never be seen on SO again...maybe it will help someone else.)

Comment: Yeah i am aware that sampling w/o replacement is impossible if new popsize is larger than source size and new popsize is 0. In this context that's not a problem. 
PS and thank you for effort.